# How to fix the error "Error "npm WARN is out of date json3@3.3.2: please use your own JSON object instead of JSON 3"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to test the application on Windows. 
Link to the application - [github.com - Leinox/GanttManager](https://github.com/Leinox/GanttManager)

- I installed `Node.js v12.6`.
- I am using the console - `c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js\Node.js, command line.lnk`.
- I put the project in the folder - `c:\test\visualStudio\1485\fl\`.

**I am doing:**
1. Launched the console: `c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js\Node.js, command line.lnk`.
2. Go to the folder with the project `cd c:\test\visualStudio\1485\fl\`.
3. `npm install`.

**See the result on the screen.**
  [image]

**Result text:**

```
In your environment, use of Node.js 12.6.0 (x64) and npm is configured.
C:\Users\admin> cd c:\test\visualStudio\1485\fl \
c:\test\visualStudio\1485\fl> npm install
npm WARN is deprecated json3@3.3.2: please use your own JSON object instead of JSON 3
The npm notification created by lockfile as package-lock.json. You must fix this file.

93 packages from 342 participants are added and 472 packages for 46.319 are checked with
46 vulnerabilities found (18 weak, 17 medium, 10 high, 1 critical)
run `npm audit fix` to correct them, or` npm audit` for details
c:\test\visualStudio\1485\fl>
```

**Questions**
1. How to fix the error `npm WARN is obsolete json3@3.3.2: please use your own JSON object instead of JSON 3`?
2. Is the `npm WARN problem now outdated json3@3.3.2: please use your own JSON object instead of JSON 3` problem or will the application work without removing this remark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `json3` [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json3) package:

> JSON 3 is **deprecated** and **no longer maintained**. Please don't use it in new projects, and migrate existing projects to use the native `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` instead.

Your application will still work but it is highly recommended not to use for production. As this package is no longer maintained by the original team.

Answer (score 1):

> How to fix the error

See [the JSON3 documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json3) which says:

> **Unmaintained** 
>  JSON 3 is **deprecated** and **no longer
>   maintained**. Please don't use it in new projects, and migrate
>   existing projects to use the native `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`
>   instead.

---

> will the application work without removing this remark?

Probably.